# jquery append var to end of url

Tags: jquery, append

I have the follwoing jquery which opens all external links in a new window:

```
$("a[href^='http']").not("[href*='<?php bloginfo('url');?>']").attr('target','_blank');
```

This will show somehting like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

However i would like to adapt this and add a variable to the end of the url for tracking purposes. So it will look something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com?myvarhere=true" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) version that takes a [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) as its argument

```
$("a[href^='http']").not("[href*='<?php bloginfo('url');?>']").attr('target', '_blank').attr('href', function (i, href) {
    return href + '?somevar=somevalue'
});
```

*Note: The callback implementation may have to be more complected if you want to check whether the url already has another parameter if so you will have to use `&` to append the new param*

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can do it

```
var myVariable = "some string";
$("a[href^='http']").not("[href*='<?php bloginfo('url');?>']")
.attr('target','_blank').attr('href', function(_, h){
   return h + "?" + myVariable + "=true";
});
```